# interesting bug in setting time for alarm

Tags: android, time, android-alarms

I have created a reminder app which gives notification "n" days before a fixed date. 
I came across an interesting bug while trying out the program. I have made the code such that if the "nth day" is before the current time the alarm does not set.

However there is a bug somewhere in the code. If i set an alarm for today (dec 6), only n=0 should set the alarm, however the alarm also gets set if i enter in number 25 to 50. if i set n to 25 alarm is set to 31st dec and if n is set to 50 alarm is set to today i.e. 6th december.

The code i am using to subtract time is:

```
Long i = c.getTimeInMillis() - n*24*60*60*1000;
c1.setTimeInMillis(i);
```

also

- value of `i` for `n = 0` is **1386315000678**
- value of `i` for `n = 50` is **1386289967974**

CurrentTimeInMillis is **1386337498776**

Is there something wrong with the code? Or is this something to do with how time converts to milliseconds in android?

Comment: why did my question get voted down so quickly?

Comment: has it got something to do that there are 25 days left in 2013?

Comment: no i am doing only milliseconds subtraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used :

```
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0-n);
c1.setTimeInMillis(c.getTimeInMillis());
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, n);
```

this works without giving the funny unexplainable bug